# cannot start application in deis, how to debug?

Tags: coreos, deis, fleet

I run `deis scale cmd=1 -a my-application` in my deis cluster

But got below response

```
Scaling processes... but first, coffee!
Error:
503 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE
detail: aborting, failed to create some containers
```

I wonder how to debug what cause this error.

I use coreOS fleet as a scheduler

Please advise

Comment: which Deis version do you have? v1 or v2?

Answer (score 0):

> I use coreOS fleet as a scheduler

This would indicate you're using Deis v1.x, which is pretty old by our own standards. (I work for Deis.)

If you're just getting started or at least not already into production with v1.x and stuck with it, consider using Deis Workflow (v2.x) instead. It sits on top of Kubernetes, which is a much better and more reliable system than Fleet was for orchestrating containers. That *and* lots of resources and effort have gone into making Workflow a product that is truly leaps and bounds bette than its predecessor.

Comment: Thanks @kent, we just move to use deis2 on top with GCP kubernetes now. :)